# Multithreading concurrency between two threads

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, block

I'm trying to make two threads. One for write ordinal numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) (one by one) into an external variable (`config1.variable1`) and other thread to read these values (one by one) from the variable `config.variable1`.

I have two files one for the code and other named `config` for the `config1.variable`. I manage the concurrency problem with `acquire()` and `release()` but I expect that the reader thread to write on the screen: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` and no other order of the numbers such as `1,3,2,4,6,5,7,8,9,10`, but it doesn't work.

The code is this:

```
import threading
import config1
import time


def function1():

    contador = 0
    hilo_actual = threading.current_thread().getName()
    while contador < 20:
        print('waiting for block', hilo_actual)
        block.acquire()
        try:
            contador = contador + 1
            config1.variable1= config1.variable1 + 1

            print('bloqued by', hilo_actual, contador)
            print('config1.variable1', config1.variable1)
            time.sleep(5)

        finally:
            print('releasing block by', hilo_actual)
            block.release()

def function2():

    contador = 0
    hilo_actual = threading.current_thread().getName()
    while contador < 20:
        print('waiting for block', hilo_actual)
        block.acquire()
        try:
            contador = contador + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print('config1.variable1 in thread 2', config1.variable1)

        finally:
            print('release blocking by', hilo_actual)
            block.release()

block = threading.Lock()
thread1 = threading.Thread(name='h1', target=function1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(name='h2', target=function2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Comment: Where is config1?

Comment: config1 is a file in the same directory. This file have one variable called variable1.